# Printing lines of a file in ruby

Tags: ruby, file, printing

I have literally just started using Ruby, and I'm looking for a possible alternative to using "gets" for file input... I'm trying to write a simple warmup program that will print out the longest line of a file, like so:

```
def findMax
  maxlength = 0

  while line = gets

    if line.length > maxlength then      
      maxlength = line.length
    end

  end

  return maxlength

end


def printLines num
  while line = gets
    if line.length == num
      puts line
    end
  end
end


printLines findMax
```

Pretty simple. Find the maximum length, and the use that to print out the longest line, nothing fancy yet. However, whenever I run it with ruby longest.rb < (file) , I get nothing. Is this because I can't use gets in the second while loop because it has nothing more to read? What can I do as an alternative? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your file name is `foo.txt` use [`File#readlines`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/IO.html#method-c-readlines) to read all the lines in the file into an array then [`Enumerable#sort_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) to sort the lines by their `size`(or `length`) and [`Array#last`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-last) to pick the last item in the sorted array

```
File.readlines("foo.txt").sort_by { |line| line.size }.last
```

Comment: Can you explain how this works? I'm not sure how to use any of the File functions and I definitely don't know how to get the name of the file I input into the program. Is there some way to do this?

Comment: @user3290526 I just added an explanation at the top of the answer, if its not clear enough feel free to ask, and I would clarify